# How to choose a WDK version (Out of several installed) using vcxproj/Msbuild

Tags: windows, msbuild, wdk, vcxproj

I have a build environment where 1 SDK version and several WDK versions are installed using "winwdksetup.exe" and "winsdksetup.exe". I also have a vcxproj file with "PlatformToolset" set as WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0.

How can I modify this vcxproj file to ask MsBuild to pick up a particular version of WDK out of the several that are installed on my build system?

I tried the default MsBuild command to build both debug and release binaries. They assume the most recent version of the WDK that is installed.